# How can I hide my application's form in the Windows Taskbar?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, taskbar

How can I hide the name of my application in the Windows Taskbar, even when it is visible?

Currently, I have the following code to initialize and set the properties of my form:

```
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
this.Controls.Add(this.eventlogs);
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
this.Name = "Form1";
this.Text = "Form1";
this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Minimized;
this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

Comment: Is your app visible in Taskbar and you want it hidden? or your app should be visible but not shown in the task bar? what is the exact question?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

To prevent your form from appearing in the taskbar, set its [**`ShowInTaskbar`** property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar.aspx) to False.

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```